# Unable to Read JSON String

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services

I'm getting a JSON string as below

```
[
    {
        "id": 20,
        "title": "a",
        "allDay": true,
        "start": "2012-12-04 00:00",
        "end": "2012-12-07 00:00",
        "color": "#eb491d",
        "startDate": "/Date(1354559400000)/",
        "endDate": "/Date(1354818600000)/",
        "Location": "a",
        "StartDatestr": "2012-12-04",
        "EndDatestr": "2012-12-04",
        "StartTime": "00:00",
        "EndTime": "00:00",
        "Alert": false,
        "Repeat": false,
        "RepeatDays": 0,
        "CalendarID": 13,
        "CustomerNo": 593963,
        "CustomerName": "test_apple",
        "IsProspect": true,
        "Description": ""
    }
]
```

When I check the length as below it returns "1"

```
console.log(myAppointment.length);
```

But when I try to access as below it gives Undefined error.

```
var myAppointment = JSON.parse(data.d);
sessionStorage.CustomerID = data.CustomerNo;
console.log(sessionStorage.CustomerID);
```

I have no idea. Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here

Comment: Your JSon data seems to wrapped in an array. Can you try myAppointment[0] in you code.

Comment: data.CustomerNo is what is undefined as it should be myAppointment.CustomerNo. then again, is this an array or not? then it should be myAppointment[0].CustomerNo.

Comment: `console.log(myAppointment.id);` does not give you the length of myAppointment, it gives you the id of the appointment.

Comment: sorry my bad I chagned it to `myAppointment.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your parsing code to:

```
var myAppointment = JSON.parse(data.d)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

change the second line like below:

```
var myAppointment = JSON.parse(data.d);
sessionStorage.CustomerID = myAppointment.CustomerNo;// from data.CustomerNo
console.log(sessionStorage.CustomerID);
```

you were trying to access the parsed piece from the data object.